# MYSQL View and summing fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help I have been scouring the web and haven't been able to find something too similar. I have a MYSQL database for my Golf League.  I need to display standings by creating a view from this database.  There are 2 people per team, my primary key in 'players' is 'id' there is also a teamID (numerical value 1 - 20, 20 teams) for each player which corresponds to their teammates.  Basically what I need is a view that contains 'teamID', both players 'LName' (maybe an 'LNameA','LNameB'), and a sum of the two players 'points' field.  I have never summed a field from one person and another or created a view in MYSQL.

EDIT:

I was trying something like

```
CREATE 
VIEW standings1
AS SELECT teamID, LName, points
FROM players
```

but need teamID to be the primaryKey of the view which will contain each players last name, and their points summed together.

Comment: Although the wording of your question is weak, it is sometimes better to show some of the sample data / table structures for your question, instead of in-line table.column.id.ranges...  Can you list the structures of the tables in question as its not clear if both teammates are on a single row, or its properly normalized to a team/player per entry, and the player's table to have last name, first name, etc  The query is probably very simple once those pieces are provided.

Comment: My apologies first post, the players are all on there own rows they share a teamID with one other player so I can attempt to group the two separate entries together.  I'm attempting to display standings with PHP and figured creating a view which I have never done would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create view standings as
  select teamId, group_concat(lname separator ', ') as TeamMembers,
    sum(points) TotalPoints from players
  group by teamId
```

Oh, one more thing. If you want to have the names of the players in different fields (group_concat just separate them by commas, but it is still a single field) you can use this query:

```
create view standings as
  select a.teamId, a.lname as player1, b.lname as player2,
  a.points + b.points TotalPoints
  from players a
  join players b ON a.teamId = b.teamId AND a.id >= b.id
  group by a.teamId, a.id
  having count(*) = 2
```

That way you can play better with the names in PHP without having to parse the ", "

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your table structure, you will need a `JOIN` against the table's own `teamID`.  I'm assuming the `teamID` refers to a team, and is not the id of the player.  The trick here is to join two copies of the table on the same `teamID`, but where the player ids are non-equal. That should produce the pair of players per team.

```
CREATE VIEW standings AS
(
SELECT
  p1.teamID AS teamID,
  p1.id AS p1id,
  p2.id AS p2id,
  p1.LName AS p1LName,
  p2.LName AS p2LName,
  p1.score + p2.score AS totalScore
FROM
  /* JOIN on matching teamID and non-matching player-id (so you don't get the same player twice) */
  players p1 JOIN players p2 ON p1.teamID = p2.teamID and p1.id <> p2.id
);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer, Mostachos did the trick.  Thank you though.